# Convert String To DateTime (d MM yyyy)

Tags: c#, string, datetime, uwp

How to convert a `String`, such as `01 Juni 2015` into `DateTime`?

I try i, but display error message (as shown below):

[image]

Code:

```
string urlPath = "website";
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{


};
var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(urlPath), new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    RequestException();
}

string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData1)
{
    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();

    string tanggal = groupObject["tgl"].GetString();
    BukuAudio file = new BukuAudio();
    string[] formats = { "d MMM yyyy" };
    var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(tanggal.Text, formats, new CultureInfo("id-ID"), DateTimeStyles.None);
    file.Tanggal = n;
    datasource.Add(file);

}
```

Note:

Date is binding from `JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use four `M` (`MMMM`) instead of three `M` (`MMM`)since your month is `Juni` not `Jun`:

```
string[] formats = { "d MMMM yyyy" };
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(tanggal.Text, formats, new CultureInfo("id-ID"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

It is OK to have single or double `d`, because your format is `01 Juni ...`, but if your format is `1 Juni ...`, then you should use single `d`

Answer (score 1):

it should be `MMMM` (not `MMM`),  use  `"d MMMM yyyy"` as format.

**MMM:**   is for displaying the three-letter form of the month represented in the `DateTime` (like "Jan").

**MMMM:** is for displaying the full month string, properly capitalized. An example is "January

So you could modify your code to

```
string[] formats = { "d MMMM yyyy" };
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(tanggal.Text, formats, new CultureInfo("id-ID"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format you are specifying is `d MMM yyyy` while the date you are trying to parse is `01 Juni 2015`. These do not match, so it fails the conversion.

To make it work, change your format to `dd MMMM yyyy`.

MSDN has the list of DateTime format strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx